# What is difference between java measure frameworks like Metrics and Apache sirona?

Tags: java, architecture, metrics

The frameworks like [Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/) and [Apache Sirona](http://sirona.incubator.apache.org/) have similar features for application measurement.
so what is mainly difference between them? are they just competing projects or may they focus on different areas?

Do you use them in production environment? and what is your experience?

any comments or feedbacks will be appreciated.

BTW: the sirona have web monitor feature that Metrics not, but i suppose it will be achieved by using metrics + [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/)